# Swift Firebase match UID keys with a array of UID strings

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to figure out how I can match the Strings which are Firebase UID's in my "data" array with the keys that I am extracting from the firebase call. I need to match the Strings in the "data" array with "key" and then I will be able to manipulate the data how I want.

```
 var data = [String]()

 Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
        print(allUsers)
        print("Printing all users right here")
        for user in allUsers {
            let key = user.key
            print(key)
            print("Printing the keys right here come and check this out in the print")

        }
    })
```

[image]

[image]

**My try, answer not in this code**

```
 Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            self.businessUID = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                for item in dict {
                    let json = JSON(item.value)
                    let businessUid = json["uid"].stringValue
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUid {
                            Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                                guard let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
                                print(allUsers)
                                print("Printing all users right here")
                                for user in allUsers {
                                    let key = user.key
                                    print(key)
                                    print("Printing the keys right here come and check this out in the print")
                                    if key == uid {
                                        print(key)
                                        print("printing the matching keys here")
                                    }

                                }
                            })
                            print(uid)
                            print("Printing the uids here")

                            Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.businessessuids).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                                print(snapshot)
                                print(self.businessessuids)

                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    })
```

**UPDATE: Found matching values but cannot save**

```
Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for snapChild in snapshot.children {
                if let user: Dictionary? = (snapChild as! DataSnapshot).value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let businessUID = user!["uid"] as! String
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUID {
                            let key = uid.jsonKey
                            print(key)
                            //print(uid)
                            print("checking uid's")
                            //let name = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
                            let Ref = Database.database().reference().child("testing")
                            let saveUID = Ref.child(key).child("their_name")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: Can you attach your Firebase table of `allUsers` ?

Comment: What is it that you want to see? All you would see if the parent "Businesses" then the UIDs then the data that uid's hold

Comment: Yes what `allUsers ` contains ? more precisely, the structure of `allUsers`.

Comment: Just added it. Thats just a sample because it keeps going for a while lol

Comment: Got that. Thanks. Let me dig into this.

Comment: I really appreciate the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190477/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-lukas-bimba).

Comment: The *data* array is empty so there would be nothing to match. Also, there’s no code in the question that does anything with that array either. Perhaps some code was omitted? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Yes, I had been trying different ways to access and match these UID values from the string array to the snapshot but none were working and I was thinking that I should just leave out my trial and error so it doesn't confuse anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some changes in snapshot. Though I haven't verify as I don't have any Firebase database setup at my end as yours.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            for snapChild in snapshot.children {

                if let user: Dictionary? = (snapChild as! DataSnapshot).value as? [String : AnyObject] {

                    debugPrint("User uid: ", user!["uid"] as! String)
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Replace your call with above code snippet and let me know if you are still having any issue.

**Note:** You can also improvisation you all user structure into model for better use.

Comment: Hey, just seeing this. I am going to check it out and let you know.

Comment: I understand why you said that "var data = [String]()"  is empty, yet it isn't. Imagine it has 2 uid strings within it and whats needed is a compare to "user" for matching UID's. Im posting code I was trying before. This code I am posted is not with your answer just my attempts.

Comment: With my added code, you'll see I compare the JSON string UID by doing "for uid in self.data"

Comment: Hey can you check out my update on your code? I matched the values but cannot save because "uid.jsonKey" is not a proper String.

Comment: I am currently trying some other methods of attack

Answer (score 0):

This works. Great Success!

```
Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for snapChild in snapshot.children {
                if let user: Dictionary? = (snapChild as! DataSnapshot).value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let businessUID = user!["uid"] as! String
                    for uid in self.data {
                        if uid == businessUID {
                            let key = uid.description
                            print(key)
                            print("checking uid's")
                            let Ref = Database.database().reference().child("testing")
                            let saveUID = Ref.child(key).child("tested")
                            saveUID.setValue("String")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: That's awesome!